# Pink salt for cooking steak

Tags: salt, steak

I've been curious about pink salt for a while now and I was wondering if it would be ok to use it for cooking steak? Or should i just stick to the regular table salt?

- sorry for the confusion, guys. My mom's friend gave her himalayan pink salt and I'm supposed to prepare steak for them so i was just wondering if I could use the himalayan pink salt that she has. I normally cook with iodized salt and have zero idea about other salts. Hope my question makes sense this time. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello Xtine, your quesiton is ambiguous. There are different ingredients known as "pink salt", as Stephie pointed out. You already started getting answers where the person who wrote it assumed a certain kind, but did not say which kind - that's a recipe for confusion! You can use the small grey "edit" link to tell us which kind you mean, and we can then reopen the question.

Comment: Yes, Himalayan Pink Salt is perfectly fine to use. I have a grinder of it at home too, great stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use pink salt unless you are following specific guidelines for food preservation. You could easily end up poisoning yourself or others if your are not careful.

Edit: I should add that I am referring to pink curing salt. The Himalayan pink salt is a different story and can generally be substituted for table salt. However if you are not 100% positive whether it is curing salt, don't use it as a seasoning.

Comment: Careful: "Pink salt" may be curing salt or salt with traces of iron oxide or similar.